# Google OR-Tools (using SCIP solver) - How to access the intermediate solutions found by the solver?

Tags: python, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming, scip

I'm new to Google OR-Tools.

Using Python, I implemented a MIP model with SCIP as a solver. The objective function is for minimization (*solver.Minimize(C)*) and I am accessing the final solution through *solver.Objective().Value()*.

However, I also need to access the **intermediate solutions** that the solver finds, before reaching the final one, and their **timestamp**. (The final goal is to plot a graph with the solutions evolution through time).

I tried to use a while loop:

```
solutions_evolution = {} # dict to store miliseconds (as keys) and solutions (as values)
localtime = (solver.wall_time()) #in miliseconds
limit_break = localtime + 60*5*1000 #sets a time limit of 5 minutes 

while (localtime <= limit_break) & (status != pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL & status != pywraplp.Solver.FEASIBLE):
new_localtime = (solver.wall_time())
solutions_evolution[new_localtime] = solver.Objective().Value() 
localtime = new_localtime
```

But it's not working since *solver.Objective().Value()* gives only the final solution.

I've been struggling for days. Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In non C++ languages, you cannot access the solver object, and incumbent callbacks are not accessible in python.

You can use solution pool though with SCIP.

Just run `Solve()`, then loop on `NextSolution()`.

If your problem is purely integral, you can use the CP-SAT solver (directly, not through the linear solver wrapper). It supports solution callback in python.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm facing another issue. The solution pool works but my objective function ( solver.Minimize(C) ) instead of decreasing over time is, in fact, increasing. I've added the code " while solver.NextSolution():    localtime = solver.wall_time() 
   makespan_evolution[localtime] = C.solution_value()" right after the solver.Solve(). What I'm I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose it prints out solutions in the reverse order they were found.

Comment: You're right @LaurentPerron! However, the loop on NextSolution() is not able to access/output the optimal value (I know, in advance, the optimal values of my MIP problem). For example, if the optimal value is 262. The loop outputs: 263, 264, 268, ... In other words, it "skips" 262. Any suggestion on how to also "grab" that value? Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried to reach the optimal value using solver.Objective().Value() but it also returns the "263".

Comment: The first (optimal) solution is reached just after `Solve()`. Then previous solutions can be reached through `NextSolution()`.